# jQuery radio validation - highlight all labels for radio

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, radio-button, label

I'm using jQuery validation to validate a form with a radio button set on it (set = two radio buttons for this example).  The radio buttons with labels are below.  The form is on a jQueryUI dialog.

```
<input type="radio" name="chooseMe" value="Yes" id="radio_yes" /><label for="radio_yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="chooseMe" value="No" id="radio_no" /><label for="radio_no">No</label>
```

I grabbed the highlight/unhighlight code from the validation plugin page on jquery.com
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate
(go to the "Options" tab and search for "unhighlight")

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
},
```

The first problem i'm having is when validated as required, only the "Yes" label is highlighted.
The second problem is if I don't resolve the validation issue and cancel out of the jQueryUI dialog, then come back into the dialog, the "Yes" label disappears completely.

To resolve the first issue, what i want to do is highlight both the "Yes" and "No" labels.  So, working on the highlight code, i would need to get the name of the input ("chooseMe") from the element id, then from that name, for all the id's associated with that name ("radio_yes" and "radio_no"), highlight all the labels.  Of course, then there's the converse for the unhighlight code.

Since i have several radio button sets in the form, i need this to be generic (no hardcoding "chooseMe", etc.)

Does that sound reasonable?  If so, the only problem is i don't know how to do that :)

Thanks in advance.

jsFiddle as requested:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bd688/4/

Comment: could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this iteration of the jsfiddle highlights both labels:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bd688/6/

The idea is to get the name of the element and look for all the other elements of the same name, then apply the same code you were applying.  So I just changed this:

```
$(element.form).find('[name='+element.name+']').each(function (i, sameName){
   $(element.form).find("label[for=" + sameName.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass); 
});
```

EDIT: Ok, so it turns out jQuery.validate doesn't really like you using its errorClass and applying it to labels.  I made another class and it seems to be working:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bd688/7/

Comment: Works great except one thing.  If i don't choose a radio button and click submit once, the labels are correctly highlighted.  if i click submit a second time, the labels go away

Comment: Huh, I saw that and stepped through the code.  What's happening is the jQuery.validate plugin is hiding and showing the elements with class 'error'.  What you're doing here is a little non-standard from what jQuery.validate is used to, so I think it'd be best to use a different error class.  I'll edit your fiddle to see if that solves it.  One moment please :)

Comment: @Milimetrid.  Thanks again - works like a charm.  Would you recommend checking to see if the element is a radio button and only doing the part that applies to radios (assuming labels associated with them) and the other for the other elements?

Comment: I'd say keep the logic the same but highlight the radio button itself instead of the label.  So keep the logic we worked out that find all radios by the same name, but leave the labels alone.  It doesn't make sense that the label has an error on it if you think about it.